# Automatic replace of inheritance with composition in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, refactoring, resharper, automated-refactoring

My question is about how to automatically replace inheritance with composition in Visual Studio (currently VS 2015).
So, we have a base class `Person`, with properties like FirstName, LastName etc, and several classes that inherit from it, like `User`, `Student` etc.. I have tried to find a way to do this automatically using the built in tools of Visual Studio and ReSharper, but couldn't find any. I know that these tools are powerful and have many refactoring options, but couldn't find a solution to this specific requirement. Is it possible to do this with these tools or some other VS plug in?

Update,
As per comments, here's some code:

Here's the base class `Person`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Base type for all types that represent a person in the system.
/// </summary>
[Table("Persons")]
public class Person : BaseEntity, IImportEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(9)]
    public string PersonID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string PassportNumber { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string TempIDNumber { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string NickName { get; set; }

    // Additional properties, omitted...
}
```

Here's one class that inherits from it, `Student`:

```
[Table("Students")]
public class Student : Person
{
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string NickFamlyName { get; set; }

    public int? NationalCode { get; set; }

    public int? IdentityType { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LeavingDate { get; set; }

    public int? CodeEntitlementToTuition { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StudentTypeID { get; set; }

    public int? StudentCharacteristicTypeID { get; set; }

    // Additional properties, omitted...
}
```

Now here's the desired result:

```
[Table("Students")]
public class Student
{
    public Person PersonDetails { get; set; }  // Notice the containment of Person in this class

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string NickFamlyName { get; set; }

    public int? NationalCode { get; set; }

    public int? IdentityType { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LeavingDate { get; set; }

    public int? CodeEntitlementToTuition { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StudentTypeID { get; set; }

    public int? StudentCharacteristicTypeID { get; set; }

    // Additional porperties, omitted
}
```

And the refactoring tool should do this change, inserting class `Person` in its inheritors and also update calls to `Student` to delegate calls to `Person`'s properties via the new property `PersonDetails`, for example:

```
var firstName = someStudent.PersonDetails.FirstName;
```

instead of:

```
var firstName = someStudent.FirstName;
```

Thanks,
ashilon

Comment: Can you give examples of the before and after code?

Comment: Sure, I'll update the post.